me sale el error NoReverseMatch at / y no se como solucionarlo, hace horas que estoy revisando las urls y estan bien ingresadas, alguien se da cuenta?
ERROR:
NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'Carro' not found. 'Carro' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 5.1.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'Carro' not found. 'Carro' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.13/lib/python3.13/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 831, in _reverse_with_prefix
Raised during: PapeleraPatriciosApp.views.index
urls:
from django.urls import path

from carro import views

app_name="carro"

urlpatterns = [

    path('',views.carro, name="Carro"),

    path('agregar/<int:producto_id>/', views.agregar_producto, name="agregar"),
    path('eliminar/<int:producto_id>/', views.eliminar_producto, name="eliminar"),
    path('restar/<int:producto_id>/', views.restar_producto, name="restar"),
    path('limpiar/', views.limpiar_carro, name="limpiar"),
]

views:
from django.shortcuts import render

from .carro import Carro

from productos.models import Producto

from django.shortcuts import redirect


    def carro(request):

        return render(request, "carro/carrito.html")
    

html:
    <ul>
        <li class="login_list"><button class="login_item" ><a href="#"><img src="{% static 'PapeleraPatriciosApp/images/login.png'%}" alt="login"></a></button></li>
        <li class="login_list"><button class="login_item" ><a href="{% url  'Carro'%}"><img src="{% static 'PapeleraPatriciosApp/images/carrito.png'%}" alt=""></a></button></li>
    </ul>


Error simple pusiste esto from .carro import Carro en mayuscula pero en la función está en minúscula, la solución en tu url.py:
from .carro import carro

